# Does SELinux allow the apache user to read /etc/passwd file?

Tags: selinux

I was experimenting and learning SELinux on Alma Linux 9.2. The intention was to build a flask application that has a file inclusion vulnerability and show how SELinux can prevent the vulnerability to protect certain files that should not be accessible to an attacker even if the flask application was compromised. To test this, I created a text file in a user's home directory and attempted to access it via the flask application and SELinux enforced. SELinux blocked it. So far, so good. Then I attempted to read the `/etc/passwd` file via the flask application and it allowed it. I am not sure why! I thought the `/etc/passwd` was sensitive enough for SELinux to block unauthorized access to it. Here is the output from `ls -Z` of the two files.

```
system_u:object_r:passwd_file_t:s0 /etc/passwd
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 /home/vagrant/test.txt
```

I am not sure if this is intended behavior.

Comment: As a general rule `/etc/passwd` is not considered sensitive. The information there is needed for applications to look up UID numbers and to display human friendly usernames for example.

Comment: Test with `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: `/etc/shadow` is well protected by file permissions alone, even with SELinux disabled.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat my initial comment:

- As a general rule `/etc/passwd` is not considered sensitive. The information there is needed for applications to look up UID numbers and to display human friendly usernames for example.

A second consideration:

- Unless you create a custom SELinux context for your custom application/daemon, it will not  run with any specific protections / restrictions. (And effectively only the conventional filesystem privileges deny access.)

You can check the current SELinux context of a running daemon with the `-Z` option in `ps`. What you see will depend a bit on how you launch your daemon but for [example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/using_selinux/index#writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux):

```
ps -efZ | grep mydaemon

system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 root 4117    1  0 16:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/mydaemon
```

shows `unconfined_service_t` and that means: no restrictions, no SELinux policy.

---

The [Red Hat SELinux manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/using_selinux/index#writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux) provides a quick intro in how to create such a custom SELinux policy:

1. Generate a custom policy:
   `sepolicy generate --init /usr/local/bin/mydaemon`
2. Rebuild the system policy with the new policy module using the setup script:
   `cd /home/example.user/mysepol ; ./mydaemon.sh`
3. Relabel the corresponding part of the file system using the restorecon command:
   `restorecon -v /usr/local/bin/mydaemon /usr/lib/systemd/system`
4. Restart the daemon, and check that it now runs confined by SELinux
5. Now you should be seeing SELinux denials / errors.